# Folder with images in makefile

Tags: directory, ide, makefile, anjuta

I have been using anjuta to make some programs. I have made a folder in the `src` directory of the program to store all the images and icons. ( `/src/images/icons` )

However when i build the tarball the folder does not exist in the compressed file, so I guess I have to include it in my Makefile. How can I edit the makefile so that the images are included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem without modifying my MAKEFILE at all. On the other hand I don't know if that solution is acceptable or it's more like an alternative and temporary one.

After creating the tar.gz archive, I opened it with archive manager and clicked *'Add a folder to this archive'* then selected the *'images'* folder to be added inside the *'src'* directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AUXFILES := /src/images/icons/files` for each file. I don't actually know for sure, but nobody else seems to care. I got this from http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile